# How to place elements vertically and not on to overlay each other

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an element with an image. The problem is when the browser is on a mobile size the  top of the image gets cut by the navbar. Any ideas on how to make it move downwards so its not cut. Im new to css and bootstrap.
The link to the page is here:

i would like to avoid Z-index for now as i dont want to tamper with the z-index sequencing of the whole theme

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
    //Some more stuff like a form and a few list items (text)
      </div>
 </nav>
```

The element with an image is here:

```
  <section id="about" class="about-section text-center">

  </section>

  <!-- Projects Section -->
  <section id="projects" class="projects-section bg-light">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- Featured Project Row -->


      <!-- Project One Row -->
      <div class="row justify-content-center no-gutters mb-5 mb-lg-0">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="img/liomi.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="bg-black text-center h-100 project">
            <div class="d-flex h-100">
              <div class="project-text w-100 my-auto text-center text-lg-left">
                <h4 class="text-white">Misty</h4>
                <p class="mb-0 text-white-50">An example of where you can put an image of a project, or anything else, along with a description.</p>
                <hr class="d-none d-lg-block mb-0 ml-0">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </section>
```

below is some media queries around navbar and mainNav

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #mainNav {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-brand {
    padding: .5rem 0;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  #mainNav .nav-link {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
```

The part with  has styling as like below(not everybit included):

```
.projects-section {
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.projects-section .featured-text {
  padding: 2rem;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .projects-section .featured-text {
    padding: 0 0 0 2rem;
    border-left: 0.5rem solid #64a19d;
  }
}

.projects-section .project-text {
  padding: 3rem;
  font-size: 90%;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .projects-section .project-text {
    padding: 5rem;
  }
  .projects-section .project-text hr {
    border-color: #64a19d;
    border-width: .25rem;
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```

If i can have the whole the perfume bottle showing and not cut

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I would much rather you offer ideas for now. I am afraid i dont know which part of the code must i post. The theme has a couple of css files as well as a long html code. I will respond with a description of the solution once you offer ideas and hopefully that is sufficient for others.

Comment: @Screwtape007 no it definitely is NOT. we need to see your code, and some description on what you have tried so far. Otherwise Im afraid nobody will help you.

Comment: I have added some code

Comment: Ok i think i have added enough detail - please let me know if this helps - thanks